# Converting QuerySet to JSON when selecting fields

Tags: json, django, django-queryset

I am trying to convert to json a list of values selected via Django queries.

My query is:

```
city_list = Address.objects.values('city').distinct()
```

where Address is

```
class Address(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    streetAddress = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ", " + self.streetAddress + ", " + self.city + ", " + self.state + ", " + self.zipCode
    def natural_key(self):
        return {"streetAddress":self.streetAddress, "city":self.city, "state":self.state, "zipCode":self.zipCode}
```

I am trying to convert it to a json like this:

```
{ "cities" : [ {"city" : "New York"}, {"city" : "Los Angeles"}, {...} ]}
```

I tried this:

```
jsonData = json.dumps(city_list)
```

but the error says that city_list is not JSON serializable. In the error screen, the string looks like:

```
[{'city': u'Baltimore'}, {'city': u'Berkeley'}, {'city': u'Austin'}...
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: can't you manually make a  json serializable value?

{"cities: json.dumps(city_list) }

Comment: Of course, but there are other methods. I posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: pass by list

```
city_list = list(Address.objects.values('city').distinct())
jsonData = json.dumps({"cities" : city_list})
```